# Jquery automatic slide

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have a div where testimonials will appear.
I want to slide it left to right automatically and change another testimonial.

How can I do that using jquery? I'm using wordpress for this.

here is the code

```
            <div class="testimonial-box fl">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>
            <ul class="testi-post-s">

                <?php query_posts('cat=222&showposts=2'); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <li class="clr">

                    <article>

                        <div class="testi-post-box clearfix">

                            <div class="testi-post-p"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

                        </div>

                    </article>

                </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </ul>
            <?php else: ?>
            <h3>No posts to display</h3>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: the easy way is just use some built-in content slider, and integrate it according to your need.

Comment: Trying following plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonials-widget/, you can also use cycle plugin to fullfill your requirement.

Comment: Personally I used [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) for this website [here](http://myjsf.org/) - and I had the content sliding.